# How to design a simple 1D transfer function for volume visualization?

Tags: color, visualization, image3d

Consider a volume (MRI Head) from (http://www9.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/External/vollib/).

I wish to design a simple 1D Transfer Function which will assign/map each intensity value to a specific colour and opacity values. This also requires to specify the number of key points to specify the bins and I want this number to be decided dynamically.

For example,

```
Image3D[img, 
  ColorFunction -> 
    (Blend[
       {{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0]}, 
        {0.5, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]}, 
        {0.6, RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0.15]}, 
        {1, RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1]}}, #1] &)]
```

This colour function is created using the option `ColorFunction` and sets the number of key points and opacity values manually.

I want to get the color and opacity values in the following way:

```
colour = cf[img];   (* cf is a user defined color function *)
opacity = of[img];  (* of is the user defined opacity function *)
```

One way to achieve this is to assign colour and opacity values running a loop for each pixel or set the number of bins or key points based on the histogram and assign the values using some conditional statements.

Is there any smart alternative to implement this 1D transfer function?

#### Edit

Consider, I wish to have five bins with different intensity ranges for the given volume:

Bin1: Intensity range -> [0, 0.2]; Colour and opacity -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0.15, 0];

Bin2: Intensity range -> [0.2, 0.4]; Colour and opacity -> RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.15, 0.2];

Bin3: Intensity range -> [0.4, 0.6]; Colour and opacity -> RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4];

Bin4: Intensity range -> [0.6, 0.8]; Colour and opacity -> RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.15, 0.8];

Bin5: Intensity range -> [0.8, 1]; Colour and opacity -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, 1];

How can I implement this as a transfer function?

Comment: So `ImageData@img`? I'm not sure I understand you question.